# SQL query not working in php but working in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am messing around with OOP mysqli. And I stumbled upon this problem:

> There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engine`.`users` ( `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL, `USERNAME` ' at line 1]

This is the PHP code:

```
    function InstallDB($db){
    $sql = 
    "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `$this->dbname`; ".
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$this->dbname`.`$this->users` ( ".
    "`ID` INT(11) NOT NULL, ".
    "`USERNAME` varchar(60) NOT NULL,".
    "`PASSWORD` varchar(60) NOT NULL,".
    "`EMAIL` varchar(100) NOT NULL,".
    "`IMAGE` varchar(250) NULL,".
    "`LEVEL` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'".
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;".

    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$this->dbname`.`$this->settings` (".
    "`DOMAIN` varchar(60) NOT NULL,".
    "`SLOGAN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,".
    "`EMAIL` varchar(100) NOT NULL".
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('SQL['.$sql.']<br>There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']<br>');
    }

    echo "Installed!<br>";
}
```

Tried different quote marks, no luck.
I also echoed the $sql, copied it and executed in phpmyadmin, it worked perfectly. But still it won't do anything inside of PHP.
Thanks.

Comment: Why all the concatenation? Simplify your code. PHP allows for line breaks in strings. use them.

Comment: I think the problem with the multiple command in one query, because the error message appeared from second row.

Comment: @JohnConde this is only the result of trying multiple things :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi_query instead query, because you would like to multiple query not only one. As you can see the issue appeared right away after first query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Yep, that worked. I was thinking about this, I even googled but all I could find was transactions witch I didn't want to use. Thank you.

Comment: could you accept my answer as a right answer please?

Comment: Sure, there was a 2min cooldown so I couldn't do it right away. Thank you again.